# Text classification using discriminative features

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I tried to classify text using word or character n-gram discriminative features which means that features appear at least 90% in one class. I am trying to use sklearn, but I couldn’t find how to implement it.

I am looking at CountVectorizer/TfidfVectorizer from sklearn but I couldn’t find how to specify feature selection by classes.

Can you suggest a method on how to implement this task?

Comment: add some data and code if you have